# How to write a junit test for outputStream.write IO IOException

Tags: java, junit, ioexception

I have the following code

```
public static void writeToOutputStream(byte[] bytesArr, OutputStream outputStream) {
    try {
         outputStream.write(bytesArr);
        }
    catch (IOException e) {
           throw new NetModelStreamingException(
                "IOException occurd during writing to stream. Error 
                 Message:" + e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

I would like to write a JUnit to test my code will catch IOException if it happens.

PS: NetModelStreamingException is a custom Exception class that extends RuntimeException.

Comment: Well, create a class that extends OutputStream and throws an IOException when its write method is called, pass that OutputStream to your method, and check that your method throws what you expect it to throw. Using a mocking framework makes that just a little bit easier, but not much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JUnit4+ a method to test that exception handling is as expected could look like this (note that you need to fail the test if no exception is thrown).

```
    @Test
    public void testWriteToOutputStreamExceptionHandling() {
        //Dummy object for testing
        OutputStream exceptionThrowingOutputStream = new OutputStream() {
            public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
                throw new IOException(); //always throw exception
            }
            public void write(int b) {} //need to overwrite abstract method
        };

        try {
            YourClass.writeToOutputStream(new byte[0], exceptionThrowingOutputStream);
            fail("NetModelStreamingException expected");
        }
        catch (NetModelStreamingException e) {
            //ok
        }
    }
```

If you need that dummy object in other test methods as well, you should declare a member variable in your test case and initialise it in a `setUp`-method annotated with `@Before`. Also, you can hide the `try-catch`-block by declaring it in the `@Test` annotation.

This way, the code would look like this:

```
private OutputStream exceptionThrowingOutputStream;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    exceptionThrowingOutputStream = new OutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            throw new IOException();
        }
        @Override
        public void write(int b) {}
    };
}

@Test(expected = NetModelStreamingException.class)
public void testWriteToOutputStreamExceptionHandling() throws NetModelStreamingException {
    YourClass.writeToOutputStream(new byte[0], exceptionThrowingOutputStream);
}
```